# First excited states of the Heisenberg model on a bipartite lattice/graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, many-body

In the antiferromagnetic quantum Heisenberg model
\begin{equation}
H=J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} X_i X_j + Y_i Y_j +Z_i Z_j,  ~~~(J>0)
\end{equation}
if the underlying interaction is *biparitite*, i.e. if all spin labels $i$ could be divided into two subsets $A$ and $B$, and interactions only appear between those two, we have the Marshall/[Lieb-Mattis theorem](https://nanojournal.ifmo.ru/en/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/NPCM92P196-205.pdf). They tell us that the ground state of such Heisenberg model will have total spin $S_{\mathrm{tot}}=0$ as long as the bipartiteness is balanced, i.e. $|A|=|B|$.

**My question:**
Are there any known results about the first excited state (FES) for such systems?

For example, I know that in general (not necessarily bipartite) Heisenberg models, the FES can have $S_{\mathrm{tot}}=1$ or $S_{\mathrm{tot}}=0$, depending on the details (like they see in e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.02476.pdf denoted by $\Delta S$ and $\Delta T$ etc). But it seems to me the only time when the FES actually becomes another $S_{\mathrm{tot}}=0$ state is when you introduce nontrivial frustration violating the bipartiteness.
So, my current conjecture is that the FES is always a triplet state $S_{\mathrm{tot}}=1$ for bipartite cases. Are there any rigorously known results in that direction? Of course, if there's an explicit counterexample, that would be super appreciated as well!

Please note that I am only considering finite size systems here, so that the question becomes well- (or at least more-easily-) defined, not needing to worry about the thermodynamic limit.